# Using PHP to delete many rows in a large table from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble deleting many rows in a large table. I am trying to delete 200-300k rows from a 2m rows table.

My PHP script is something like this

```
    for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++){
    $query="delete from record_table limit 100";
    $queryres=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());;
}
```

this is just an example of my script where I will delete 100 rows at a time running for 1000 times to delete 100k records.

However, the PHP script just seems to keep running forever and not returning anything.
But when I tried to run the query from command line, it seems to delete just fine, although it takes about 5-6 minutes to delete.

Could there be something else that is preventing the PHP script from executing the query? I tried deleting 100k in one query and the result is the same too.

The query that I really wanted to run is "DELETE FROM table WHERE (timeinlong BETWEEN 'timefrom' AND 'timeto'"

The timeinlong column is indexed.

Comment: you have no WHERE clause, how are you determining what rows to delete? And the 100 at a time loop just seems crazy

Comment: why are you deleting without WHERE clause? why not try "DELETE FROM record_table" which deletes all records from the table ?

Comment: You've got 2 semicolons, not sure if it was copied and pasted or retranscribed

Comment: There is a WHERE clause. This is just a test query, in the real query, I will be deleting using between 2 dates. WHERE timeinlong between A and B.

Comment: cant answer questions when you decide to leave out half the details.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have an ID field so you can just do something like this:

```
 $delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM records WHERE id > 1000");
```

That would leave the first 1,000 rows and remove every other entry.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you deleting using loop so many times it's not a good way to delete. If you have any id (auto incremented) then use it with where clause 
(e.g delete from `record_table` where id< any ID)

Or if you want to delete it with looping then for a long time you should also use set_time_limit(0) function to keep PHP script executing.

Comment: No, I do not have any ID or auto-increment column.

The real query I will be using is "DELETE FROM table WHERE timeinlong BETWEEN 'timeFROM' and 'timeTO';"

Comment: @OutlawZ We are not getting what you really want to delete? do you want to delete all the records between timefrom and timeTO then it's a simple query "delete from table_name where timelong between timeFrom and timeTo"

Comment: yes... it is a simple query, the only problem is the time it takes to delete those records... I need a solution to delete those records in a faster or more efficient way...

Comment: @OutlawZ add Index to timelong using following command "Alter table_name add index index_name('index_name')"

Comment: The column is indexed. But, somehow it doesn't make deleting any faster.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps adding a field to track deleted items will work for you.  Then rather than actually deleting the rows, you update 'deleted' to TRUE.   Obviously your other queries need to modified to select where deleted equals FALSE.  But it's fast. Then you can trim the db via script at some other time.